# jQuery: code is being executed even if it shouldn't

Tags: jquery, ajax, if-statement

In the following code, i'm recycling the same Ajax function for more forms. One of this form must be reset after data has been submitted. Problem is that the reset code (on the 6th line) is being executed even when the `if (data)` event occours. How could this be?

```
$('input[type="button"][id^=data_]').click(function () 
    if ($(this).attr('id') == 'data_update') {
        [...]
    } else if ($(this).attr('id') == 'data_submit') {
        [...]
        var extra_success = $('form[name="data_submit"] input[type=text]').val('');
    };
    $.ajax({
        [...]
        success: function(data) {
            if (data) {
                $(div_for_response).html(data).css('color','red');
            } else {
                $(div_for_response).html('Success!').css('color','green');
                if (extra_success) {
                    extra_success
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: try to use return false; then execution stops there itself

Comment: @asimshahiddIT you mean after `var extra_success = $('form[name="data_submit"] input[type=text]').val('');`? this will stop the whole code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that I think you try to assign a funcion to your variable `var extra_success` while you are actually executing it in that moment. Try to change your code like this:

```
$('input[type="button"][id^=data_]').click(function () 
    if ($(this).attr('id') == 'data_update') {
        [...]
    } else if ($(this).attr('id') == 'data_submit') {
        [...]
        var extra_success = function() {
            $('form[name="data_submit"] input[type=text]').val('');
        };
    };
    $.ajax({
        [...]
        success: function(data) {
            if (data) {
                $(div_for_response).html(data).css('color','red');
            } else {
                $(div_for_response).html('Success!').css('color','green');
                if (extra_success) {
                    extra_success();
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

This way you assign a function to your variable that you can then call later.

Comment: this is it! thanks Dim! ;) 
i thought i've tried this solution already but it was breaking the code...i might have done a typo...

Answer (score 1):

Try using ===
You need exact comparison

```
$('input[type="button"][id^=data_]').click(function () 
    if ($(this).attr('id') === 'data_update') {
        [...]
    } else if ($(this).attr('id') == 'data_submit') {
        [...]
        var extra_success = $('form[name="data_submit"] input[type=text]').val('');
    };
    $.ajax({
        [...]
        success: function(data) {
            if (data) {
                $(div_for_response).html(data).css('color','red');
            } else {
                $(div_for_response).html('Success!').css('color','green');
                if (extra_success) {
                    $('form[name="data_submit"] input[type=text]').val('');
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: nothing changes, and i don't think problem is there...i've updated the code as i posted it wrong. this way you can understand better the situation: `$('form[name="data_submit"] input[type=text]').val('');`, that is contained in `extra_success`, is being executed both if the `if (data)` is true or false

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are resetting the val when you are creating the variable try this instead :

This meen that you will pass in the first `if` creating the variable. Even if you go in `if(data)` the value was delete when the variable was create.

```
$('input[type="button"][id^=data_]').click(function () 
    if ($(this).attr('id') == 'data_update') {
        [...]
    } else if ($(this).attr('id') == 'data_submit') {
        [...]
        var extra_success = $('form[name="data_submit"] input[type=text]');
    };
    $.ajax({
        [...]
        success: function(data) {
            if (data) {
                $(div_for_response).html(data).css('color','red');
            } else {
                $(div_for_response).html('Success!').css('color','green');
                if (extra_success) {
                    extra_success.val('');
                }
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Should do the trick if your `if` statement are good.

Comment: that's what i first thought but how to solve this? your suggestion doesn't work...but even if it worked, i've projected `extra_success` to work even with the other forms, so it might not always have to assign an empty value to something...

Comment: Then there must be something else outside of the snippet of code because this code should work as expected.

Comment: ok, my mistake (typo in the code): it works thanks...but it's not the best solution as i explained before. at the moment i can leave it this way, but is there a better solution?

Comment: Always depend of what you need to do with your form and how you target then. You could alway put a `if/switch` inside the `if(extra_success)` for different action if you know what to target.

Comment: thanks sebastien, dim has provided the perfect solution for my case! :)